# Typescript: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' when creating a count up counter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code for a simple count up counter:

```js
function useInterval(callback: any, delay: any) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();
  savedCallback.current = callback;
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      savedCallback.current();
    }, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
}

useInterval(() => {
  setTimer(timer + 1);
}, 1000);
```

While the code works fine, I am getting the following error for this line: `savedCallback.current();`

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
> (property) MutableRefObject.current: undefined

Any ideas on how this can be fixed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callback` is of type `any` so it can be `undefined` and since

```js
savedCallback.current = callback;
```

`savedCallback.current` can be `undefined` so when you try to invoke it typescript tells that you

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

so what you can do is to give the same type to `savedCallback` and `callback`
I guess `callback` is a function:

```js
function useInterval(callback: () => void, delay: any) {
  const savedCallback = useRef<() => void>(() => {});
  //...
}
```